# $d\mid n\Longrightarrow d\leq\sqrt n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $d\mid n\Longrightarrow d\leq n$

Ok, but need to go further, I can say (if yes, how to demonstrate) that $$d\mid n\Longrightarrow d\leq\sqrt n$$

Comment: Since $10| 20,$ and $10 > \sqrt{20},$ I assume you mean something else.

Comment: @IgorRivin Also $n\mid n$, but $n\le\sqrt{n}$ happens quite rarely. `;-)`

Comment: $d$ needs to be prime.

Answer (score 5):

What you *probably* want to prove is that if $dd'=n$ then at least one of $d,d'$ is less than $\sqrt n$. If both were $>\sqrt n$ then $dd'>n$, which is impossible.

Comment: +1 from me for spotting what the OP was probably trying to show.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true. As $25|100$ but $25\not\leq \sqrt{100}=10$.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true. For example, $8 \mid 16$ but $8 \not \le 4 = \sqrt{16}$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general, even if you add the assumption that $d\ne n.$ Consider for example $n=36$ and $d=9.$ Then $9\mid 36,$ but $9>6=\sqrt{36}.$